# Python script help - assign certain materials to some particular objects

Tags: python

First post here. Using Blender 2.8 and learning the basic of scripting. Can someone help me with a assigning certain materials to some particular objects. Any help would be great, many thanks.

```
import bpy
objects = bpy.data.objects

material_01 = bpy.data.materials['red_material']
material_02 = bpy.data.materials['blue_material']
material_03 = bpy.data.materials['yellow_material']

for obj in objects:
    if 'Object_cube1' in obj.name:
        obj.data.materials[0] = material_01

for obj in objects:
    if 'Object_cube2' in obj.name:
        obj.data.materials[0] = material_02

for obj in objects:
    if 'Object_cube3' in obj.name:
        obj.data.materials[0] = material_03

for obj in objects:
    if 'Object_cube4' in obj.name:
        obj.data.materials[0] = material_01
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `get(name)` and `startswith(...)`**

Using the get method of a collection, objects and materials in this case,  if an object doesn't exist with  name it returns `None` which is boolean false.

Here I've made a helper method, and added a call to add default material "Material" to default cube object "Cube" or any name other starting with it, eg "Cube.001", but not "BigCube"

Taken a punt that you are looking for objects that start with those names, for which `startswith` is ideal.

```
import bpy

def assign_mat(ob_name, mat_name):
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
    obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith(ob_name)]
    for ob in obs:
        if mat:
            ob.data.materials[0] = mat
    return obs and mat


if assign_mat("Cube", "Material"):
    print("assigned Material to Cube[*]")
```

Recommend something like

```
pairs = (("Cube", "Material"),
         ("Blob", "BlobMaterial.001"),
         ("Cone", "Material"),
        )

for ob_name, mat_name in pairs:
    assign_mat(ob_name, mat_name)
```

If nothing is assigned

```
if not any(assign_mat(ob_name, mat_name) for ob_name, mat_name in pairs):
    print("Assigned Nothing????")
```

Comment: Thank you so much batFINGER, will give this a try.